# Nginx to block IP's behind load balancer is not working

Tags: nginx, x-forwarded-for

I'm running a Nginx 1.12.2 webserver in Google Cloud (1.1.1.1) with a load balancer of GCP (2.2.2.2) accessing from a client (3.3.3.3). I am trying to allow traffic only from the IP of the load balancer or the IP of the client, but when I try it blocks all the traffic.

This is my nginx.conf:

In http:

```
include blockips.conf;
```

In server:

```
server {

proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
set_real_ip_from    2.2.2.2
real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive   on;
```

In the `blockips.conf` I have:

```
allow 3.3.3.3
allow 2.2.2.2
deny all
```

However, when I make the request to the web server, it is not taking the IP of the load balancer or the client but a different IP.

```
2018/12/27 20:14:42 [error] 3121#0: *45 access forbidden by rule, client: 6.6.6.6
```

In X-Forwarded-For appear both IPs I need:

```
2018/12/27 20:14:42 [debug] 3121#0: *45 http header: "X-Forwarded-For: 3.3.3.3, 2.2.2.2"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.